# multiple rows in one row

Tags: t-sql, jpa

So I have a table, which looks like this:

```
ID  |  parentID  |   name   |  typeID
---------------------------------------
1   |      2     |  thing1  |    1
2   |      4     |  region1 |    0
3   |      4     |  region2 |    0
4   |     NULL   |  region3 |    0
5   |      3     |  foo1    |    2
5   |      3     |  foo2    |    2
6   |      3     |  bar1    |    3
```

What I need, is an output that is like this:

```
ID  |  region  |   thing  |  foo  |  bar
--------------------------------------------
1   |  region1 |  thing1  |  NULL |  NULL
2   |  region2 |  NULL    |  foo1 |  bar1
3   |  region2 |  NULL    |  foo2 |  NULL
4   |  region3 |  NULL    |  NULL |  NULL
```

With this

```
Select ID,
    (CASE WHEN [typeID] = 0 THEN [name] END) AS region,
    (CASE WHEN [typeID] = 1 THEN [name] END) AS thing,
    (CASE WHEN [typeID] = 3 THEN [name] END) AS foo,
    (CASE WHEN [typeID] = 5 THEN [name] END) AS bar
FROM [my].[dbo].[foobarthingtable]
where type = 0 OR type = 1 OR type = 3 OR type = 5
```

I get this (logically):

```
ID  |  region  |   thing  |  foo  |  bar
--------------------------------------------
1   |  NULL    |  thing1  |  NULL |  NULL
2   |  region1 |  NULL    |  NULL |  NULL
3   |  region2 |  NULL    |  NULL |  NULL
4   |  region3 |  NULL    |  NULL |  NULL
5   |  NULL    |  NULL    |  foo1 |  NULL
6   |  NULL    |  NULL    |  foo2 |  NULL
7   |  NULL    |  NULL    |  NULL |  bar1
```

How do I get those "foos", "bars" and "things" in the same row as the (parent) regions?
A JPA way (`CriteriaQuery`) would also be nice, since I have to display this as an overview on a JSF page.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've got it

```
;With NumberSequence( Number ) as
(
    Select 1 as Number
        union all
    Select Number + 1
        from NumberSequence
        where Number < 100
),
base_list AS (
    SELECT
       ISNULL(t2.name, t1.name) as Region,
       t1.name,
       t1.typeid
    FROM foobarthingtable t1
    LEFT JOIN foobarthingtable t2 ON t1.[parentID]=t2.id AND t2.typeID = 0
)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY reg_list.Region, reg_list.Number) as ID,
    reg_list.Region AS region,
    thing_list.name AS thing,
    foo_list.name AS foo,
    bar_list.name AS bar
FROM (
    SELECT
       t1.Region,
       NumberSequence.Number
    FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT 
          ISNULL(t2.name, t1.name) as Region
       FROM foobarthingtable t1
       LEFT JOIN foobarthingtable t2 ON t1.[parentID]=t2.id AND t2.typeID = 0
       WHERE t1.typeID in (0,1,2,3,5)
    ) t1
    CROSS JOIN NumberSequence
) as reg_list

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
       bl.Region, bl.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bl.Region, bl.name) rn
    FROM base_list bl
    WHERE typeID =1
) thing_list ON thing_list.Region=reg_list.Region AND reg_list.number=thing_list.rn

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
       bl.Region, bl.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bl.Region, bl.name) rn
    FROM base_list bl
    WHERE typeID =2
) foo_list ON foo_list.Region=reg_list.Region AND reg_list.number=foo_list.rn

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
       bl.Region, bl.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bl.Region, bl.name) rn
    FROM base_list bl
    WHERE typeID =3
) bar_list ON bar_list.Region=reg_list.Region AND reg_list.number=bar_list.rn

WHERE thing_list.name is not null or foo_list.name IS NOT NULL OR bar_list.name IS NOT NULL OR  reg_list.Number=1

ORDER BY     reg_list.Region,    reg_list.Number
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you should GROUP result set by ID

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96ff3/12)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
Select 

    (case when [typeID]=0 then ID ELSE parentID END) as ID,


    (CASE WHEN [typeID] = 0 THEN [name] END) AS region,
    (CASE WHEN [typeID] = 1 THEN [name] END) AS thing,
    (CASE WHEN [typeID] = 3 THEN [name] END) AS bar,
    (CASE WHEN [typeID] = 2 THEN [name] END) AS foo
FROM foobarthingtable
where typeid in (0,1,3,2)
)

select id,
 MAX(REGION) REGION,
 MAX(THING) THING,
 MAX(FOO) FOO,
 MAX(BAR) BAR 
from CTE group by id
```

Comment: You have lost ID=1 in your result.

Comment: YOU, SIR, just deserve the FINEST coffee in town! Works like a charm! Thx a LOT!

Comment: BTW: I'm just realising, that it gets only ONE thing, foo and bar for one region. So, if I have multiple things/foos/bars in one region it only displays one. In my question the 2nd table: row with ID 4 won't be displayed...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement

```
;WITH PivotData AS
(
SELECT
    ISNULL(t2.name, t1.name) as ParentRegion, -- grouping column
    t1.name, -- aggregation column
    CASE t1.typeid
       WHEN 1 THEN 'thing'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'foo'
       WHEN 3 THEN 'bar'
    END as mycolumn -- spreading column
FROM foobarthingtable t1
LEFT JOIN foobarthingtable t2 ON t1.[parentID]=t2.id AND t2.typeID = 0
WHERE t1.typeID in (0,1,2,3,5)
)
SELECT ParentRegion, [thing], [foo], [bar]
FROM PivotData
PIVOT(MAX(name) FOR mycolumn IN ([thing], [foo], [bar]) ) AS P
ORDER BY ParentRegion;
```

Comment: thx for the reply, but it doesn't work as expected. in just gave me again the last table, with an own row for each thing, foo and bar.

Comment: thx! It works almost as needed after few slightly modifications:
"LEFT JOIN foobarthingtable t2 ON t1.[parentID]=t2.id AND t2.typeID = 0
where t1.typeID in (0,1,3,5)"
TypeID=0 because we have custom region names.
And I've ordered the results first by region, then by things, then by bars etc. No big deal at all.

My only left problem is: There is region and thing OR region and foo OR region and bar in a row. So if there is a thing AND a foo AND a bar in region2, it gives me 3 separate rows for the same region instead of 1 with region, thing, foo and bar in one single row...

Comment: Aha, so you need grouping by region, not ID. Corrected

Comment: correct. but if I don't select t1.equipmentID, I get the same as in @valex solution: every region has only ONE row and displays only one thing foo and/or bar for a region.